# opengl on Linux : unable to use a correct version

Tags: opengl, glfw, glew, fedora-25

I tried to build a program using glfw + glew on Fedora 25.
part of it is:

```
int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,3);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,3);
    mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(1024,768,"NONE",nullptr,nullptr);
    if(mainWindow == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout<<"Creating window ERROR.\n"<<std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    .....
}
```

If I use `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);` to get the version 3.3, it'll be unable to create window though.

My hardware supports openGL 4.1.

upd: got the answer....

Comment: For Mesa, you should be requesting a core profile, otherwise you will get OpenGL 3.0.  This is similar to behavior on macOS.  Do not bother with the forward compatibility bit, it is obsolete and doesn't really do anything.  I would run `glxinfo | grep version` to make sure that a known good program can create a context of the desired version.  Look at the core profile version string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uncomment `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_*,*)` there.
While using core profile with `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)`,
the explicit version needs to be requested.

Thanks to the comment of Dietrich Epp.

By the way, can anyone tell me how to get such information?